# Buttons disabling in a random order, Rails/javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a bunch of buttons, 3 in total.

These buttons are messing with my head ha, The buttons are disabling in a weird order. If i press button 2, it'll disable (it disables because its submitting data to the database) Once it disables i can click button 3 to submit the data but it won't disable. However. Button one will.

Its kinda the same for other methods. If you press button 3 it'll disable and i can disable the other two. If i click button one, I can't disable the other two but it data submits fine.

When explaining this would you be gentle? I've only just started with rails haha!

Heres the code;

```
<div id="a" style="margin-right: 5px; float: left;">
  <% if @conference_status.cross_charged_user_id.present? %>
      <button id="a" class="btn btn-primary" disabled="disabled">Disabled</button>
  <% else %>
      <%= link_to 'Cross charged to Client', admin_conference_status_path(@conference_status, status_name: 'cross_charged_use'), class: "btn btn-primary", method: :put, remote: true, prompt: 'Are you sure?' %>
  <% end %>
  </div>
  <div id="b" style="margin-right: 5px; float: left;">
    <% if @conference_status.payment_received_comm_user_id.present? %>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" disabled="disabled">Disabled</button>
    <% else %>
        <%= link_to 'Payment received Commission', admin_conference_status_path(@conference_status, status_name: 'payment_received_comm'), class: "btn btn-primary", method: :put, remote: true %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <div id="c" style="margin-right: 5px; float: left;">
    <% if @conference_status.payment_received_client_user_id.present? %>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" disabled="disabled">Disabled</button>
    <% else %>
        <%= link_to 'Payment Received', admin_conference_status_path(@conference_status, status_name: 'payment_received'), class: "btn btn-primary", method: :put, remote: true %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

And heres the js.erb

```
<% if @conference_status.cross_charged_datetime.present? %>
$('#a').html('<button class="btn btn-primary" disabled="disabled">Disabled</button>');
<% elsif @conference_status.payment_received_comm_user_id.present? %>
$('#b').html('<button class="btn btn-primary" disabled="disabled">Disabled</button>');
<% else @conference_status.payment_received_client_datetime.present? %>
$('#c').html('<button class="btn btn-primary" disabled="disabled">Disabled</button>');
<% end %>
```

Comment: Explain the question more clearly.

Comment: make sure every time you click a button, you get a response from the server.

Comment: Sorry didn't think it was hard. I'm needing the buttons to disable in any order rather than just backwards

Comment: are you getting response from the server properly?

Comment: well the buttons stay disabled after refreshing the page but i'd prefer not to refresh after button click

Comment: i also don't get the "Are you sure" prompt appear on the first button

Comment: Also, one of your buttons has id='a' (same as enclosing div). You don't want to have duplicate ids on the page.

Comment: I didnt notice that Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay,

I fixed this using the If Command repeatedly. The elsif and else seemed to be messing it up. So just changing them all to If in the Js.erb and adding `<% end %>` works fine

Sam